# NodeJS - Mongoose populate trouble

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am running my app on Node 8.4.0 MongoDB 3.4 and I can't get Mongoose population to work.

I have two models:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Carrier = require('./Carrier.js');

var ValuationFormSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    assignmentnumber: {
        type: Number,
        default: Number()
    },
    assignmentpartnumber: {
        type: Number,
        default: Number()
    },
    currency: {
        type: String,
        default: String()
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        default: String()
    },
    iagree: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: Boolean()
    },
    totalValue: {
        type: Number,
        default: Number()
    },
    carrier: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Carrier'
    }],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        default: String()
    },
    submitted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    send: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    template: String,
    surveyvolume: Object,
    agreement: Object
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ValForm', ValuationFormSchema);
```

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Item = require('./Item.js');

var CarrierSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    items: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
    }],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Carrier', CarrierSchema);
```

and this is my API

```js
app.post('/api/valuationform/populate', function(req, res) {
        var email = req.body.email;
        ValForm.find({'email' : email},{'submitted' : false})
            .populate('Carrier')            
            .exec(function(error, docs) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(docs));
                    res.json(docs);
                } else {
                    res.send('{ error: ' + error + ' }');
                }
            });
    })
```

Instead of getting the carrier objects i get the id's of the objects.
There are multiple carriers per valforms.

The result looks like this:

```
{
        "_id": "58d24ff9c195a72784108d85",
        "assignmentid": 123441,
        "__v": 0,
        "send": false,
        "uuid": "044da37c-8976-4f80-b103-d07c43a97af2",
        "createdAt": "2017-03-22T10:20:41.260Z",
        "carrier": [
            "58d24ff9c195a72784108d86",
            "58d24ff9c195a72784108d8d"
        ],
        "totalValue": 40000,
        "iagree": false,
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "currency": "SEK",
        "assignmentpartnumber": 0,
        "assignmentnumber": 0
    }
```

I want the carriers to be returned as objects not objectid's.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: As far as I know You have to take care on that on Your own. You have to extract it manually in Your exec function.

Comment: sorry for stupid question, but these carrier objects exist with id 58d24ff9c195a72784108d86 and 58d24ff9c195a72784108d8d?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try in lowercase `carrier` as defined in your schema.

```
ValForm.find({ email: email }, { submitted: false }).populate('carrier').exec(...);
```